# How to save the id and token of the user.

Tags: objective-c

thanks for the help

I have made a simple login system with email and password when the user logs in he gets a hidden userID and  token from the webservice to navegate the app.

I want to save the UserID and the token in the app to use it in other classes but i dont know how to do that.

I had the idea of creating a void that holds the information but when i try to access it from other classes it doesn't work, i also tryied NSUserdefautls but i have been told that doing that is not safe so i gave up on that.

I tried keychain but i also managed to fail using that.

I really dont know what to do, can someone help me :)?

i just need a light in the end of the tunel here !haha

thank you very much.

Comment: NSUserdefautls is fine to save a simple key. I am not sure why it isn't safe. You can also look into core data /sqlite to store the keys in the database.

Comment: `NSUserdefaults` is unsafe from the perspective os the user being able to view it and change it rather easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keychain is a good option for this, get Keychain wrapper code to make it easier.

Look for keychain helper software in [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/?q=keychain), either add the pod or just copy the source files into your project.

Comment: thank you for the website it was really useful :))))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` for this. But it is not a safe way to do this.

You can use third-party classes like [Lockbox](https://cocoapods.org/?q=lockbox) to store data in keychain securely. You can find more of these classes in [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/).

Comment: That Lockbox is really nice it even has in app purchase , thank you for the advice  i will look more into it :).